# Errors while Web Scraping in Python with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am having several problems while scraping a website with selenium and need some help, please.

In a part of my code, every time that I run it, it loops between three different errors.

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Install Webdriver
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

website = 'https://www.interpol.int/How-we-work/Notices/Red-Notices/View-Red-Notices'
driver.get(website)
driver.maximize_window()

dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(by='id', value='nationality'))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text('Brazil')

search_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//i[@class='privacy-cookie-banner__icon-close']")
search_button.click()

search_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//button[@id='submit' and @type='submit']")
search_button.click()

pagination = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//div[contains(@id, "paginationPanel")]')
pages = pagination.find_elements(by='xpath', value='.//li')
last_page = int(pages[-2].text)

name = []
age = []
initial_page = 1


while initial_page <= last_page:
    time.sleep(6)
    container = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//div[contains(@class, "redNoticesList__list")]')
    products = container.find_elements(by='xpath', value='.//div[contains(@class, "redNoticesList__item notice_red")]')

    for product in products:
        name.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value=".//div[@class='redNoticeItem__labelText']").text)
        age.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//span[@class="age"]').text)
       
        next_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//a[@class='nextIndex right-arrow']")
        next_button.click()
        
    

    initial_page = initial_page + 1
```

The code part that return the errors is:

```
for product in products:
        name.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value=".//div[@class='redNoticeItem__labelText']").text)
        age.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//span[@class="age"]').text)
       
        next_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//a[@class='nextIndex right-arrow']")
        next_button.click()
```

The error is:
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found

It appears for the xpath of the name, age and next_button elements. Looping between them every time I run the code.

I verified that all xpaths in every page are the same for the three elements, tried different xpaths to run the code, but could not find the problem.

May someone help me with this, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to click the next button in the for loop or outside?

```py
for product in products:
        name.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value=".//div[@class='redNoticeItem__labelText']").text)
        age.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//span[@class="age"]').text)
       
        next_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//a[@class='nextIndex right-arrow']")
        next_button.click()
```

Notice the indentation.

You might want to do this instead:

```py
for product in products:
    name.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value=".//div[@class='redNoticeItem__labelText']").text)
    age.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//span[@class="age"]').text)
       
next_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//a[@class='nextIndex right-arrow']")
next_button.click()
```

and instead of sleeping for 6 second use:

```py
myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'wait_for_this_id')))
```

Comment: I did not know that the indentation could be a problem, But IT WORKED! Thanks a lot!!!